# A "fake" terminal on macOS to use during demos or conference talks

Tags: command-line, macos, terminal-emulator

I need to record some terminal sessions which I will be replaying back during demos or at conferences. I want it to look like actual typing, but without the chance of typos or other errors.

Requirements:

- Can record a complete Terminal session including Vi/Vim
- When playing back should actually execute the commands entered
- Playback should look like normal typing
- Timings between keystrokes should be editable
- Input file should be manually editable

Nice to haves:

- Can enter breakpoints to pause playback (wait on key press for example)
- Silent execution of some commands, only show output of a command within terminal

Similar software:

- [ttyrec](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/) - input files are not editable
- [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/) - input files are better, but still almost impossible to edit manually

Comment: If it's all terminal, why not just fake everything? Write a script that prints text with some delays.

Comment: It would be pretty time consuming to write a custom script each time, and also hard to fake terminal applications such as Vi/Vim